# Spingboot React Hypermedia string id

Tags: reactjs, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, hateoas

I am building a web app using SpringBoot, Hibernate, and React. I have had no troubles using the spring tutorials to create 'normal' objects with autogenerated Id's. For my user table I don't quite see the need to have an autoincrement ID which will require a separate index, so I am trying to make the username the Primary Key. (This will also make all references easier to decipher). Here is my User model :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3924062441897826838L;
    @Id
    @Column(name="username")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="role")
    private String role;
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="country")
    private String country;
    @Column(name="enabled")
    private boolean enabled;
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                CascadeType.PERSIST,
                CascadeType.MERGE
            },
            mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "createUser")
    private Set<Project> createdProjects = new HashSet<>();

    private User() {    }
    public User(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userName="+ userName+",firstName="+firstName+"]";
    }


}
```

I can't seem to get access to my primary key (userName) through the basic routes. (this.props.user.userName... in react). I understand that it's embedded in the _links, but is there any way to access it for my list page?

```
**
 * User Object
 */
class User extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }

    handleDelete() {
        this.props.onDelete(this.props.user);
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <tr>
            <td>**{this.props.user.userName} is BLANK**</td>
            <td>{this.props.user.firstName}</td>
            <td>{this.props.user.lastName}</td>
            <td>{this.props.user.enabled}</td>
            <td>
            <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>Delete</button>
        </td>
          </tr>);
      }
}
```

Is adding the auto increment id to User the only way? All help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE: Here is the output of the console.log(this.props.user) :

```
    Object

_links: Object

createdProjects: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/users/testUserName/createdProjects"}

projects: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/users/testUserName/projects"}

self: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/users/testUserName"}

user: {href: "http://localhost:8080/api/users/testUserName"}

Object Prototype

country: "TestCountry"

enabled: true

firstName: "TestName"

lastName: "TestLastName"

password: "testPword"

role: "testrole"
```

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(this.props.user)` in your render function?

Comment: I get json with all properties but no userName. `: Object
country
:
"United States"
enabled
:
true
firstName
:
“M"
lastName
:
“S"
password
:
“Xxx"
role
:
"ROLE_ADMIN"
_links
:
{self: {…}, user: {…}, createdProjects: {…}, projects: {…}}
__proto__
:
Object`

Comment: Can you put your code in your question, not here please. What's the contents of the `user` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring does not expose id of an entity class by default. You can configure it to expose id of a certain entity class. The code below should do the work.

```
public class RestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(User.class);
    }
}
```